# JS - Can't programmatically trigger button on Wattpad

Tags: javascript, wattpad

I try to click the `#profile-dropdown` element on Wattpad programmatically with the developer tools console.

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById("profile-dropdown").click();
```

But it doesn't work. It works on other sites, but not on Wattpad. What am I doing wrong?

This doesn't work either:

```
document.querySelector(".on-follow").click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because Wattpad's dropdowns are li's that are only used for formatting.  The actual click listener is in an `a` tag inside the `#profile-dropdown`.  Try running this: `document.querySelector("#profile-dropdown a").click();`

Comment: Thanks!! How about the follow button? `document.querySelector(".on-follow").click();` doesn't work and neither does `document.querySelector(".on-follow span").click();`

Comment: I actually don't have an account with them.  I was just able to figure it out by looking at similar buttons on their site without logging in.  I would say look for the `a` tags since that seems to be where they're putting their click events.

Comment: Also, if a solution answers your question, be sure to mark it as such.